# Vertical LinearLayout, making the map shrink the more controls are added

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I want to display a Google map and 2 controls below it.
How do I achieve this?! I tried it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/browser_link_context_header" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edOrderLocation"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinJobType"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The controls are not visible, the whole screen takes up the map.
I want the controls to be visible at the bottom of the screen and thus reduzing the size of the fragment accordingly

Comment: Are you trying to get a result like google map or something ? In that case you can use CollapsingToolbarLayout for that. Can you show what kind of layout you are trying to make ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/controls_container"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/browser_link_context_header" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/controls_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edOrderLocation"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinJobType"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Wow thanks, works like a charm! :) android:layout_above is doing the magic here I guess. Nice!

Comment: I would like to add one more thing, don't use android namespace repeatedly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: remove xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" from <fragment>